# Overload PHP "new" operator

Tags: php, oop

I'm looking for a way to overload `new` operator in PHP. I've already searched and it seems not to be possible. But may be there is different way to achieve what I need.

I have bunch of classes defined in different files. In order to create an instance of the class I have to include the file first. But I don't want to precede every `new` instruction with calling file including function. I'd prefer to have the `new` operator redefined so it would include if necessary the file before creating the class instance.

Is there any elegant way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, it's called an "autoloader" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

Comment: This has nothing to do with overloading

Comment: isn't what you are looking for just a constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have to include the file first

You are looking for [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) PHP feature.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: But the autoloader doesn't get to have a look at the object, so really it's nothing like overloading 'new' (as in C++, etc.)

Comment: There's no way to overload `new` operator in PHP. OP used just not fully correct wording in his question.

Answer (score 2):

From [Class posing and overloading the "new" operator](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/124-Class-posing-and-overloading-the-new-operator.html):

```
<?php
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

function callback($className) {
    if ($className == 'Foo') {
        $className = 'Bar';
    }

    return $className;
}

var_dump(get_class(new Foo));

set_new_overload('callback');
var_dump(get_class(new Foo));
?>
```

Also check **[Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**

Comment: set_new_overload is not a valid PHP function.  It looks like it probably came from this old, deprecated extension: https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers